# Searching a cell with a string of comma delimited values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

unfortunately i can't find the solution to the following problem.

I have a table (DATA) consisting of a column A with non-unique identifiers and a column B with several 4-digit codes separated by a space.

In another table (CODES) i have a column A for unique identifiers that are occuring in column A (DATA) and a column B with several, by comma delimited 4-digit codes.

[image: Example as it should be]

My goal is to check all entries in the first table (DATA) and list those NOK that have at least one code in column B identified in the other table (CODES)

I've used the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(CODES, MATCH([@A], CODES[A], 0), MATCH("B", CODES[#Kopfzeilen],0)),[@B])), "NOK", "OK"), "OK")
```

Unfortunately that only searches for the complete string in colum B (CODES) and not for every value delimited by a comma.

[image: Example as it currently is]

Is it possible to have a formula without using VBA (as this creates problems on sharepoint, where the file is being stored)?

Comment: you could make it much easier on yourself and do something like `IF(IF(FIND("code1",cell_ref)>0,1,0)+IF(FIND("code2",cell_ref)>0,1,0)+IF(FIND("code3",cell_ref)>0,1,0)>0,"NOK","OK")` assuming there is not a ton of codes

Comment: How many potentially comma separated values are there? You could write out a formula that looks to see if before the first comma matches, between the second and third matches, etc.

Comment: Additionally, you are making it harder on yourself by having to break down your search criteria first instead of making a single column list.

Comment: There are about 10 codes for every unique identifier maximum (accessories per item). The codes table basically indicates the items with certain accessories that are under review ("NOK"). Overall there are about 100 possible codes (accessories).

I also tried the approach to list an identifier in the CODES table several times with just one entry in column B (AB123 - CD01, AB123 - EF02, CD345 - ZD01, EF678 - AB34) but that didn't work with "INDEX". So a hardcoded "search term" like "code1" seems to be impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FILTERXML:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&substitute(INDEX(CODES, MATCH([@A], CODES[A], 0), MATCH("B", CODES[#Headers],0)),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),[@B]))), "NOK", "OK")
```

Make sure you change `#Headers` to your language if different than English

This will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode in Excel 2013.

[image]